# Remove all the lines if the column2 corresponds to two or more values of column1

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a tab delimited table, where:

```
GL89     AADAC
GL89     AFGAC
GL89     AFDAC
GL50     AC923
GL50     AC923
GL79     AC923
GL99     AC923
GL99     AC923
GL60     AC100
GL60     AC100
GL20     AC200
GL30     AC300
GL30     AC400
```

I want to eliminate the rows where one value of the column#2 correspond at least to 2 or more values of column#1, in this case lines below should be removed.

```
GL50     AC923
GL79     AC923
GL99     AC923
GL99     AC923
```

And keep the rest of the table:

```
GL89     AADAC
GL89     AFGAC
GL89     AFDAC
GL60     AC100
GL60     AC100
GL20     AC200
GL30     AC300
GL30     AC400
```

Is there any form? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
{ data[$2]= (data[$2]==""?"":(k[$2]==$1? data[$2] ORS: "@") ) $0; k[$2]=$1 }

END{ for(x in data) if(data[x] !~/^@/) print data[x] }' infile
```

note: I used `@` character to mark those records that should not be printed when printing and so this character should not be presented in your input file, else you will need to change that to a character other than that character (or choose set of characters as a string instead).

- `data[$2]= (data[$2]==""?"":(XXX) ) $0`, updates the value of the array `data` with the result of the `(XXX)` part if if it's not empty and append the current line to it too. the column `$2` is used as the array keys.
- the `(XXX)` part that is `(k[$2]==$1? data[$2] ORS: "@")`, sets at-sign character if the value of the same key (we used array `t` as a helper to keep the keys' latest values pairs) was differ else append its content + a newline (ORS) for that key.
- at the end all those lines that had same second column but different >1 multiple first column will be deleted as we marked those with a specifc `@` character in the code.

---

to understand the code better, you can use the `print ...` statement whenever you want to see what's happening,

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
{ data[$2]= (data[$2]==""?"":(k[$2]==$1? data[$2] ORS: "***") ) $0; k[$2]=$1 }

END{ for(x in data) print "<" data[x] ">" }' infile
```

I just marked deleted records with a at-sign character in original command showing here those that starts with the `***` mark.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk that supports `length(array)`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
$2 != prev {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    prev = $2
}
{ cnt[$1]++ }
END { prt() }

function prt(   val,i) {
    if ( length(cnt) == 1 ) {
        for (val in cnt) {
            for (i=1; i<=cnt[val]; i++) {
                print val, prev
            }
        }
    }
    delete cnt
}
```

```
$ sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 -k1,1 file | awk -f tst.awk
GL89    AADAC
GL60    AC100
GL60    AC100
GL20    AC200
GL30    AC300
GL30    AC400
GL89    AFDAC
GL89    AFGAC
```

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate data structure for this problem is the `set`  and a `dictionary`

And python has both built-in.

```
python3 -c 'import sys
ifile = sys.argv[1]
fs,ors = "\t","\n"

d = {}; L = {}
with open(ifile) as fh:
  for l in fh:
    c1,c2 = l.rstrip().split(fs)
    if c2 in d:
      d[c2].add(c1)
      L[c2].append(l.rstrip())
    else:
      d[c2] = { c1 }
      L[c2] = [ l.rstrip() ]

print(*[l
  for k,v in d.items()
  if len(v) == 1
  for l in L[k]
  ], sep=ors)
' file
```

Output:

```
GL89    AADAC
GL89    AFGAC
GL89    AFDAC
GL60    AC100
GL60    AC100
GL20    AC200
GL30    AC300
GL30    AC400
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun<sup>1</sup>, using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

The basic steps are

1. use `nest --implode` to assemble all the values of `$1` corresponding to each `$2` into a delimited list
2. filter the list to count the unique values of `$1`
3. use `nest --explode` to expand the filtered `$1` values back out as separate records

For step (2), we can de-duplicate the elements of the delimited list like `GL50;GL50;GL79;GL99;GL99` by turning them into keys in a hashmap. Unfortunately the builtin DSL string-to-hashmap functions `splitkv` and `splitkvx` only work with key-value *pairs* - there doesn't seem to be a way (by passing an empty pair separator for example) to make them turn a delimited string of keys alone into a hashmap (with arbitrary or empty values). So we have to roll our own by splitting the string into an indexed map, then turning the *values* into keys of a new map.

Note that steps (2) and (3) are only necessary because we **don't** want to filter out multiple values of the **same** `$1` value - otherwise we could simply test the length of an indexed map of the imploded string (and there would be no need to explode the result).

So

```
$ mlr --nidx --fs tab nest --ivar ';' -f 1 then filter '
  func splitkx(s,t):map {
    var m = {};
    for(k,v in splitnvx(s,t)){m[v] = 1};
    return m
  }
  length(splitkx($1,";")) == 1' then nest --evar ';' -f 1 file
GL89    AADAC
GL89    AFGAC
GL89    AFDAC
GL60    AC100
GL60    AC100
GL20    AC200
GL30    AC300
GL30    AC400
```

Notes:

1. really more for my own reference, since I doubt I'll ever be able to figure it out again